# Latex table not rendering with 5 columns but with 4

Tags: tables

So I am trying to write some latex code to render a table but when I give the parameter of four columns (\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}) it renders all nice and fine.

But then I use 5 columns and it won't render.

Code:

```
$$
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| }
\hline
 & $(x-1)$ & $(3x+4)$ & $x^2+2x+5$ & \frac{x^2 + 2x + 5}{3x^2 - x - 4}\\
\hline
$-1<x<\frac{4}{3}$ & $-$ & $+$ & +\\
\hline
$x<-1$ & \\
\hline
$x=-1$ & 1\\
\hline
$x>\frac{4}{3}$ & 4\\
\hline
$x=\frac{4}{3}$ & 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
$$
```

Comment: `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 ...2+2x+5$ & \frac{x^2 + 2x + 5}{3x^2 - x - 4}` because `\frac` has to be in math, but a `tabular` cell is text

Comment: If the whole thing holds math and is in math, you can use the array environment instead of tabular.  The difference between the two is that array needs to be in math and its contents are math, whereas tabular needs to be in text and its contents are text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Note: [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/47927)

Comment: I think it is semantically correct to set each entry in math mode, but why did you enclosed everything in a displayed math environment? If you want to center your `tabular`, use `\begin{table} \centering ... \end{table}` for that, it was designed specifically for this.